# how to connect mysql database to desktop java application using jdbc?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

how to connect mysql database to desktop java application using jdbc ?
the environment is ubuntu 12.04 Lts  i tried so many ways but all of them throw an exception on executing

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

the exception say :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

the full code is :

```
import java.sql.*;

public class CRUDForGoods {
    private Connection connection ;
    public Vector<GoodsStore> goods ;

    public CRUDForGoods(){
        try{
           DriverManager.registerDriver(new JdbcOdbcDriver());
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:dbName","root", "root");



        }
           catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("##connection");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: My goodness why are you using reflection?

Comment: Is mysql-connector.jar on your classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` not found while executing the code.

You need mysql connector to get it run (the jar includes `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`). You can find it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

Download and include the jar file in your classpath.